# Delete value Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

I started to learn about pandas and try to analyze a data

So in my data there is a column country which contain a few country,I only want to take the first value and change it to a new column.

An example First index have Colombia,Mexico,United Stated and I only wanna to take the first one Colombia [0] and delete the other contry[1:x],is this possible?

I try a few like loc,iloc or drop() but I hit a dead end so I asked in here

[image: Column with a few values]

Comment: Hey Justin, it's a good question and has some good answers. You might find this gets flagged to be closed though. Here on SO, we forbid images of code or data being uploaded, and ask to see real code, and real outputs to console, to improve overall site quality and make the questions easier to answer.

Comment: Oh I still new to SO and I didnt know about that,thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(',').str[0]
```

Consider below df for example:

```
In [1520]: df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['Colombia, Mexico, US', 'Croatia, Slovenia, Serbia', 'Denmark', 'Denmark, Brazil']})

In [1521]: df
Out[1521]: 
                     country
0       Colombia, Mexico, US
1  Croatia, Slovenia, Serbia
2                    Denmark
3            Denmark, Brazil

In [1523]: df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(',').str[0]

In [1524]: df
Out[1524]: 
    country
0  Colombia
1   Croatia
2   Denmark
3   Denmark
```

Comment: @JustinPark Please let me know if the answer worked?

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me,it work!! :) right now i still learning about split in pandas documentation,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `.str.split()`:

```
df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(',',expand=True)[0]
```